# Rename a Report Section in Crystal Reports

Tags: .net, vb.net, crystal-reports

Is it possible to rename a report section in a crystal reports using the version of crystal that is built into Visual Studio 2008?

If so how can this be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually simple, and I had just overlooked it.

If you select a section and open the properties pane there is the property (name).

Changing this updates the name on the designer.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to interpret your question.  If you mean "Given a report grouped by a field called 'L1grp', how do I rename one of those groups?" then create a new formula:

If {L1grp} = "Lisa Simpson" then "Bart Simpson" else {L1grp}

Change your level 1 Grouping from L1grp to this new formula.

I've only used the standalone CR XI Developer, but I don't see why this wouldn't work.

Comment: I mean the report sections that show in the designer as grey bars. For example the section 'details' or ' page header', if you create more they change to details a, details b etc... is there any way to rename that.

I'm not asking about grouping.